# Main breaker on load center won't open

Tags: circuit-breaker, electrical-distribution

I was in the process of connecting a Reliance generator trow over switch , although the job was completed , I was trying to shut off power to the entire house by opening the main breaker but would not open . THe load center is an old Cutler Hammer ( 1988-92_ model ) and although Iwas able to operate and shut down individual breaker , I was concern that I could not close the main .Are these main breaker like that or should I get an electrician to replace the main breaker ?

Raul

Answer (score 8):

100% you need an electrician out there ASAP.  If you can't manually trip it, there's a good chance it won't trip in an overcurrent situation and that could be very dangerous.

Your electrician will probably need to arrange this with the power company.  To do this, the power must be cut upstream, and usually this involves removing the seal on your exterior meter.